# dplyr: How to ungroup by single variable in different columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have this table:

```
week_number;day_of_week;amount
26;Monday;100
26;Tuesday;50
26;Wednesday;90
27;Monday;50
27;Tuesday;10
27;Wednesday;40
```

I want to convert it to the following using dplyr:

```
week_number;Monday;Tuesday;Wednesday
26;100;50;90
27;50;10;40
```

I know how to group by week_number and day_of_week and get the total for each. But I need separate columns for each day.

Thanks

p.d: The workaround I'm currently using relies on reshape and is as follows, but I can't believe the same can't be accomplished using dplyr:

```
library(reshape)
unpivoted_data_frame <- melt(dataframe, id=c("week_number", "day_of_week"))

final_data_frame <- cast(unpivoted_data_frame, week_number ~ day_of_week, sum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tidyverse`, we can create a sequence column by group and then do the `spread`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(day_of_week) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  spread(day_of_week, amount) %>%
  select(-rn)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  week_number Monday Tuesday Wednesday
#        <int>  <int>   <int>     <int>
#1          26    100      50        90
#2          27     50      10        40
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you have to use only functions from `dplyr`? Here is a solution using the `spread` function from `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  spread(day_of_week, amount)
dat2
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   week_number Monday Tuesday Wednesday
#         <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1          26    100      50        90
# 2          27     50      10        40
```

**Data**

```
dat <- tribble(
  ~week_number, ~day_of_week, ~amount,
  26, "Monday", 100,
  26, "Tuesday", 50,
  26, "Wednesday", 90,
  27, "Monday", 50,
  27, "Tuesday", 10,
  27, "Wednesday", 40
)
```

Comment: @akrun I think yours is probably safer to deal with some situations.

Comment: Could be, but in this case yours is compact